# TFS Online Deleted Projects Cannot Be Remove from Visual Studio Source Control Explorer

Tags: tfs, source-control-explorer

Someone in my team has decided to delete old (unused) projects from our TFS Online server and now I see a bunch of GUID text in the Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

On the right pane you can see that the projects do not exists on the TFS Online Server. Also, I logged in to our Visual Studio Online to make sure that its not there and its not.

I tried deleting the mapping and disconnecting from the server but when I connected back the GUID projects still there.

Also, I tried deleting the cache folder from "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0" nothing helps.

The Guid in the middle (in the screenshot) seems to be mapped to a project that does not exists in my local anymore and I cannot remove the mapping.

Does anyone know how to delete these projects from my source control explorer?
by the way other developers see these GUID text too. Every developer sees it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is already reported [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/411595/deleted-projects-greyed-out-in-source-control-expl.html)

Currently Azure DevOps Team is working on this issue for the fix.As of now there is no workaround for this. So, we have to wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `tf detroy` cmd. But it still shows up in Source Control.
So I deleted the Workspace containing that deleted project and it disappeared.
Now I just create a new workspace to use.
If you want to try, make sure to check-in everything first.